# Swift UILabel word wrap for Chinese?

Tags: swift, uilabel

In my UILabel, I have multiple Chinese phrases with spaces between them. However, the word wrap doesn't work on line break and half of the Chinese phrase is in the first line while the other half is in the second line. Is there a way to word wrap this?